# Is there a way to compile a c# program that generates a .exe and .pdb into a .cab and .inf?

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, cab

Here's the situation:
I'm working with Jenkins and I recieved a program made in C# with Visual Studio 2008. Now, I can compile it via commands with the **msbuild** command, but it generates the files that I said in the title up above, **.exe** and **.pdb** but I need to get a **.cab** file and **.inf**. Is there a command that I am missing or the program itself should generate those files?

Comment: cab/inf would be used for deployment, are you asking how to package the exe into a cab/inf to do that? If not, whats your ultimate aim?

Comment: You're comparing two entirely different terms. CAB/INF are being used to package and deployment. If you want to pack your files into CAB/INF, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj584918.aspx)